# Are requests of court documents recorded somewhere (NYC jurisdiction)?

Tags: new-york-city, court-records, public-records

I'm specifically concerned with the request of documents relating to arraignments, though I don't know if that makes a difference.

If a person requests the documents pertaining to an arraignment, is that request recorded, in any way, by the government? If so, I have some questions:

1. Where/how is it recorded?
2. What is recorded in regards to the request? Is the identity of the requestor recorded for example?
3. How may one access the records of people's requests? Must one be a specific kind of official, or are the requests public?